# How to call controller method from view RAILS 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, view, controller

I think I stated the title of this question right, but this is the issue:

I have the following in my SurveysController-

```
  def pull_responses
    call= "/api/v2/surveys/"
    auth = {:username => "test", :password => "password"}
    url = HTTParty.get("https://fluidsurveys.com#{call}",
                       :basic_auth => auth,
                       :headers => { 'ContentType' => 'application/json' } )
    response = JSON.parse(url.body)
    survey_ids = response["surveys"].map { |s| s["id"] }

    survey_ids.each do |x|

      call= "/api/v2/surveys/#{x}/responses/?_completed=1"
      auth = {:username => "test", :password => "password"}
      url = HTTParty.get("https://Fluidsurveys.com#{call}",
                         :basic_auth => auth,
                         :headers => { 'ContentType' => 'application/json' } )

      response = JSON.parse(url.body)
      response_count = response["count"]
      Survey.create(y: response_count)
    end
  end
  helper_method :pull_responses
```

All I am trying to do is put the variable `response_count` in my Surveys view. I may not need `Survey.create(y: response_count)`, but that was a peice of one of my attempts to get this to work. Essentially, I just want to write this in a view:

`puts response_count`

What is the proper way to put that response into a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the value to an instance variable (by adding `@` before the name) so that it will persist to the view:

```
@response_count = response["count"]
```

then in the view you can print it like so:

```
<%= @response_count %>
```